# Extracting value from onclick function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, how do I extract the number 4 from the doThisThing() function call from an onclick event:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="doThisThing(4)"></div>
```

and how do I set it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *extract*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? And why do you need to set it, too? Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do so we can better help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').attr('onclick', 'doThisThing(4)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in the function itself you will have access to it:

```
function doThisTHing(inputValue)
{
   alert(inputValue);
}
```

How you set what gets passed depends on what you are trying to pass.

Comment: What do you want to set it to?

Comment: @MonOve: In what context? Set it *when*?